# Would it be better to model preference based activity assignment as a Stable Marriage Problem or a Minimum Cost Problem?

Tags: algorithm

Students list preferences for activities.

Overall aim is to get higher preferences as often as possible.

Stable marriage or min cost flow with bipartite graph?

EDITS:

- Context: Secondary school students choosing activities for a 'fun week' at the end of the school year.
- Speed: obviously would be nice to reduce execution time, however it's not an essential thing I need to accommodate for, because after all the kids enter their preferences the member of staff just has to run it once to get all the allocations.
- Can assume the students will not lie about their preferences- they won't know the algorithm used and even if a couple lie it's not too big of a deal.

Comment: Of the two options, min cost flow fits best for a lot of different fitness functions, but you might want to think about the fine points of what you want.  If, for example, you want the solution to be Pareto optimal AND you want to ensure that it isn't to any student's benefit to lie about his preferences, then I don't think either option fits the bill.

Comment: I see, just to add additional information, speed is not a priority in this case. What do you mean by fitness functions though? Also, the context is secondary school kids choosing what activities they want to do during a 'fun week', and I'd imagine they would choose their actual preferences so covering for preference lies is something we can ignore too

Comment: @MattTimmermans I've also briefly looked at the hungarian algorithm...would that be even better than min cost flow?

Answer (score 1):

Min cost flow seems more appropriate because students have preferences, but activities do not.  Also this formulation allows an activity to support multiple students (by increasing the capacity on the arcs).

Stable marriage is appropriate when both sides have preferences.

Comment: Ah right. I was looking around and I saw that some people made the second group have a bunch of "dummy preferences" and that gave me second thoughts. So if I were to use a min cost flow with a bipartite graph I would have to make all the students come from an extra 'sink' and make all the flow capacities to the students = infinity, as well as the costs being 0?

Comment: That sounds good, but be aware that some implementations for min-cost flow will allow you to have multiple sinks (one for each student) which can avoid the extra sink.  At some point you will need to set the capacity to 1 (to ensure a student does not take the same activity multiple times), but this can either be done for the edges in the bipartite graph or the edges to the extra sink (or both).

Comment: Would you think something like this, https://imgur.com/rukW6Hu , fits the bill then?

Comment: With this graph you should also set the capacity for the initial edges (from the extra source node to the students) equal to the number of activities that they are allowed to take (probably 1 in your scenario).  Otherwise the max flow will assign a student to multiple activities.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. Would be 3-5 in my case depending on how many preferences I decide to let the students pick later on. Thanks for all the help man.

Comment: sorry to necro this thread, but during my design I also looked at the Hungarian algorithm, would you recommend me to use that instead of min cost flow?

Comment: Hungarian algorithm will only work if each student can only take one activity.

Comment: they can only take one activity each day. How would I control capacity with the hungarian algorithm though? It seems less straightforward to do so than with mincost flow...

Comment: Hungarian has no notion of capacity, it is a matching algorithm instead (although sometimes you can duplicate students to have the same effect).

Comment: I see, btw thanks for all the help man :) . Ill mull over duplicating students but I'll probably end up going with mincostflow from the looks of it.